Filtering configurable which have offer
I want to filter out all the configurable products which have offer in a collection. I have tried many filters which is working fine with simple and bundle but not working with configurable.

what does offer means?

Hi Mehran, I mean which have discount.

I want to show all the configurable product which have discount on a Grid. Any help will be appreciated. @Mehran

@sateeshchandra Please remove either this question or the other one to avoid duplication. : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/374945/filtering-all-the-configurable-product-which-have-special-price/374972#374972
