Filtering all the configurable product which have special price
I want to filter out all configurable product which have discount in Magento 2. I have tried many ways but it is filtering only simple product not configurable product. Please help.

To retrieve configurable products with a special price, you can refer to the example code provided below.
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Index;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action

{

    protected $productcol;

    public function __construct(

       \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,

       \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productcol)

    {

       $this->productcol = $productcol;

       return parent::__construct($context);

    }

    public function execute()

    {
        $products = $this->productcol->create();
        $products->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', 'configurable');
        $products->load();

        $configurableProducts = [];

        // Iterate over the collection
        foreach ($products as $product) {
        $_children = $product->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProducts($product);
        foreach ($_children as $child){
            if($child->getSpecialPrice()){
                $configurableProducts[] = $product;
        //If you need to retrieve the child product, output the `$child` and extract the relevant data as needed.
            }
        }
        }
        echo "<pre>";print_r($configurableProducts);

    }

}

